# Converting character counts to token counts

Tags: python, string, character, tokenize

My problem is the following.  I have a string that contains a few English sentences.  I also have a separate list of annotations that have been made on that string that are of the form

```
char_index_start | char_index_end | annotation
```

So for each annotation, the word (or words) that have been annotated are shown as well as where they appear in the sentence via the character index where the word(s) begin and and index where they end.  If the annotation contains multiple words then they are contiguous within the sentence.  Here is an example annotation

```
230 | 240 | 2006 Civic
```

What I want to do is convert the character index to a token index (i.e. counting tokens instead of counting characters).  The problem with this is that I cannot think of a straight-forward way of mapping character indices to token indices.  The problem is that tokenizers ignore spaces. So tokenizing the string and mapping them to character indices by assuming there is one space character between each token would not work.  For example if there was a double space somewhere, the character count would be incorrect.  I suppose one way to do it would be to make a list of contiguous whitespace character counts that occur between each non-whitespace character then map these between tokens.  However this would create problems also because a tokenizer can separate tokens that do not have any space between them.  Is there any straight-forward way of doing this?  Or existing code?

Comment: Is the Character Index Byte, codeunit, codepoint, grapheme or grapheme-cluster based? Also, which character-set has the input text?

Comment: I am not sure what those terms mean, but each character is given an index on an incremental sequential basis.  i.e. the first character is given index 1, the second is given index 2, etc.  I am also not sure what you mean by 'character-set'.  It is utf-8 if that is what you mean.

Comment: THe problem is this: THe term character is overloaded, and I was trying to determine which possible interpretation applies to your input data, and specifically whether it corresponds to the python interpretation. If it does, wonderful. If it doesn't, you must get below the python string abstraction, which will hurt.

Comment: As far as I know it corresponds to the python interpretation

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a solution in the following way.  Before I was using the nltk tokenizer to tokenize my string.  The issue was that I was not able to retrieve the character indices for the tokens that it produced (maybe it is possible but after a bit of time spent researching, I still could not find a way).  So eventually I decided to create my own regex-based tokenizer that would also give me the character indices of the tokens.  Given a string, a list of all its tokens and their indices can be found via

```
[(m.start(0), m.end(0),m.group()) for m in re.finditer("\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+",input_string)]
```

So now I was left with a list of tokens and their character indices and a list of annotations and their character indices and it was pretty trivial to match them.  Then I was left with token-level annotations which is what I wanted.